# Creating RESTful architecture to communicate between ASP.NET web app and MVC 3 App using JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, rest

I need to take GET fields from my asp.net web app (first name and last name). It needs to send that data from frontend(asp.net web app) using JSON to MVC 3 app. MVC 3 App would communicate with database, retrieve values and should serialize them into json object and POST to the front end(ASP.NET web app). Can anyone explain with a sample code how I would accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class. It allows you to send HTTP requests to any web application. As far as the JSON part is concerned you will need a JSON serializer. You could use the built-in [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class or a third party such as [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/).

So let's suppose that you have the following controller action in your ASP.NET MVC 3 application that you want to invoke:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(Bar bar)
{
    ...
    return Json(new 
    {
        status = "OK"
    });
}
```

where the `Bar` class contains some properties (could be simple or complex types):

```
public class Bar
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Now you could invoke it like this from the client side:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = serializer.Serialize(new 
    {
        firstName = "first",
        lastName = "last"
    });
    var resultJson = client.UploadString("http://example.com/foo", json);
    var result = serializer.Deserialize<Result>(resultJson);
}
```

where you would define the `Result` class to match the JSON structure returned by the application:

```
public class Result
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me a clear idea. I have walked through the steps that you provided but when I am running both MVC app and the client it throws me a 404 Not Found error at this line (client.Uploadstring("http://localhost:3198/Foo",json). Do you know why it was occuring?

Comment: @Krishh, maybe you haven't configured your asp.net mvc application so that it responds to `/foo`. This will entirely depend on your routing setup. You might need to specify a controller name as well: `/home/foo`.

Comment: I guess that was the mistake I made. Wow it worked!. Thanks a lot for explaining me the process very clearly. Thank you